# How do I extract an image from a newspost using Jsoup in android an to load into imageview?

Tags: android, html, parsing, imageview, jsoup

Here is my code, that gives me an error stating that the URL is not valid, but I'm sure that it is valid since I can get the image through the browser. This is the [link to the page](http://goo.gl/XoKPUI).

```
// Connect to the web site
Document document = Jsoup.connect(newsImg).get();
// Using Elements to get the class data
Elements img = document.select("img[src]");
// Locate the src attribute
String imgSrc = img.attr("src");
// Download image from URL
InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imgSrc).openStream();
// Decode Bitmap
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```

Comment: "error stating that to sp" => you must have been in a hurry :)

Comment: oh sorry..i'll edit it

Comment: Did you check that `imgSrc` contains the wanted full url?

Comment: yes,it has the full url

Comment: Post a second question for the other problem: "I  also need to show that image inside an `ImageView` in the activity.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below instead. See the comments in it for details.

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(newsLink).get();

// Instead of using Elements, we'll use Element class directly...
Element img = document.select("img#1").first();
if (img == null) { // Always check that the image has been foud
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to locate image in " + newsLink);
}

// Locate the src attribute. You need an absolute URL here...
String imgSrc = img.absUrl("src"); // ... so we use `absUrl`

// Download image from URL
InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imgSrc).openStream();

//...
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which image do you want, so I am assuming that you want the picture of the first news. If you open that page inside an inspector (e.g. Chrome's dev tools) you can see that the image has a relative link, like this one: `/rf/image_size_800x600/HT/p2/2016/01/05/Pictures/india-airbase-attack_a23bb650-b38f-11e5-87b3-9157ef61c9c7.jpg`, which is likely to be the motivation behind your error.

If you want to download the image you must provide the full URL, which is the base target follwed by the relative URL. In this case it resolves to: `http://www.hindustantimes.com/rf/image_size_800x600/HT/p2/2016/01/05/Pictures/india-airbase-attack_a23bb650-b38f-11e5-87b3-9157ef61c9c7.jpg`

Comment: see i have made the following changes and still it doesnt work... please help https://paste.ee/p/Tmm0C